# Struts isn't calling my servlet. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, struts

Well, basically my struts servlet isn't working right.  Please tell me if anything appears wrong below:

**Java Resources\src\bo\DisplayCartServlet.java**

```
  package action;

  import java.io.*;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

  import javax.servlet.*;
  import javax.servlet.http.*;
  import org.apache.struts.action.*;

  import bo.*;
  import dao.*;

  public class DisplayCartServlet extends Action
  {
     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
     {

       String forward = new String("success");      ;
        String productCode = request.getParameter("productCode");      

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        Cart cart = (Cart) session.getAttribute("cart");  
        if (cart == null)
        {
           cart = new Cart();
           session.setAttribute("cart", cart);
        }

        int quantity = 1;

        // Get product from product code
        Product product=null;
    try {
        product = ProductDB.selectProduct(productCode);         
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        session.setAttribute("product", product);

        // If product exists, add or remove from cart
        if (product != null)
        {
            LineItem lineItem = new LineItem();
            lineItem.setProduct(product);
            lineItem.setQuantity(quantity);
            if (quantity > 0)
              cart.addItem(lineItem);
            else
              cart.removeItem(lineItem);
         }
         session.setAttribute("cart", cart);

        return(mapping.findForward(forward));
    }

}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
                <package name="example" namespace="/example" extends="struts-default">        
                    . . . . 

                    <action name="cart" class="action.DisplayCartServlet" >
                      <result name="success">/example/cart.jsp</result>
                    </action>        

                </package>
     </struts>
```

**listProducts.jsp** link that activates the struts and servlet

```
   <div id="cartLink"><a href="<s:url action="cart?productCode=XM123456"/>">Add to   Cart</a></div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message ?

Comment: I am getting the requested resource is not available.

Comment: That's not a servlet. That's a struts1 action class. To learn what servlets actually are, read our servlets tag wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info Looking into your question history, I guess that you've lot of basic Java EE (JSP/Servlet) concepts wrong or confused. I'd suggest to take a code pause and work out some basic Java EE web development tutorials/books first to grasp the basic concepts. Learn Java EE step by step. Don't dive in a big project yet. Work from bottom to top, not from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your bluntness. . . Java SE is pretty simple; however, getting into J2EE is a lot more involved.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application isn't working correctly because you have created **a Struts 1 Action** class but you are trying to configure it with a **Struts 2 configuration** XML.

[Struts 1 and Struts 2 are very different](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/comparing-struts-1-and-2.html).

Struts 1 Configuration is called `struts-config.xml`: http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd

Struts 2 configuration is called `struts.xml`: http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd

You created a Struts 1 Action class (which as @BalusC pointed out, is not a Servlet) so you must configure it using `struts-config.xml`...

**Or,**

... you have to create a Struts 2 class to match the `struts.xml` configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the webserver logs and find the proper error.. i.e., any exceptions specific to the problem. which will help you narrow down the problem.